# Refactor to use Shorthand If or Short-Cuircuit

Tags: c#

Need some advice on refactoring the below method:

```
public static IServiceCollection Remove<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceDescriptor = services.First(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(T));

    if (serviceDescriptor != null) services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);

    return services;
}
```

I managed to extract a static method, see below

```cs
public static ServiceDescriptor GetServiceDescriptor<T>(IServiceCollection services) => 
    services.First(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(T));

public static IServiceCollection Remove<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceDescriptor = GetServiceDescriptor<T>(services);

    if (serviceDescriptor != null) services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);

    return services;
}
```

The question is if there is a way to simplify this even more?
In Javascript I can use Short Circuit to simplify the if statement like this:

```js
x==2 && dosomething();
```

But that does not seem to work in C#

All the C# gurus, help me out here, please.

**Update**

based on the below suggestions I settled on

```cs
public static void Remove(this ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, IServiceCollection services)
    => services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);

public static void Remove<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
    => services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(T))?.Remove(services);
```

Comment: Your code looks good, although you should probably use `FirstOrDefault`. `First` would never return a null value, just raise an exception if nothing matches.

Comment: That's only possible if the return type of *dosomething* is `bool`.  Low odds for that, use the [elvis operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) instead.

Comment: `if (GetServiceDescriptor<T>(services) is { } service) services.Remove(service)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify the code as much as this, if you also add another extension method for your `ServiceDescriptor` class.

```
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveSelf(this ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, IServiceCollection services)
        => services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);

    public static void Remove<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
        => services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(T))?.RemoveSelf(services);
}
```

Sample usage:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/RUcEJv

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems good. However there is one issue and I think you search short circuit solution for this.

You should use `FirstOrDefault` method instead of `First`.
If you use `First` and collection does not contain matching item, exception is raised. When you use `FirstOrDefault`, result can be null.